# Using string to output specific answers

Tags: c++

suppose that i have to output a programme in which when i enter yes it should display try again and if i enter no it should say thankyou
i have made the programme like this, please help me out in the modifications in this programme because it is not working

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string x;
    x="yes"||"no";
    while(x!="0")
{
    cout<<"Please enter your choice=  "<< x << endl;
    cin>>x;
 if (x="yes")
    {cout<< "Please enter again";}
 else if (x="no")
    {cout<< "Thankyou";}
}
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here:

```
x="yes"||"no";
```

This has basically no effect. You're reading in `x` down below.

You should replace `while(x!="0")` with `while(true)` to get an infinite loop, until you got the desired result.

Then `x = "yes"` and `x = "no"` *assign* strings. You wanted to use `==` for comparison.

With the change to `while(true)` above, you'll have to place `break;` in the "no"-branch to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should read:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x;
    x="yes or no";
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "Please enter your choice=  " << x << endl;

        cin >> x;

        if(x == "yes")
        {
           cout << "Please enter again";
        }
        else if(x == "no")
        {
           cout << "Thank you";
           break;
        }
     }

     return 0;
}
```

The single `=` operator is the assignment operator, while the double `==` operator is the comparison operator. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) is a tutorial that further explains operators. Also I think you wrote this line - `x="yes"||"no";` thinking it meant `x="yes or no";` however the disjunction `||` operator is used when combining conditionals such as, `if(x == "yes" || x == "no")`.